# Why do Google pages switch to Arabic language when my IP is from Switzerland?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, language, google-search

I use a VPN allowing me to choose a country of egress. Strangely enough, when I connect to Switzerland (and my public IP is correctly shown as Swiss by geo ip services), all the Google services and webpages switch to Arabic language! If I connect to another country (say, UK or Germany) then Google behaves normally.
I don't have Arabic language set anywhere in the preferences (and I'm using Safari on a Mac, not Chrome). Clearing cookies / temp files doesn't help, but changing a public IP does! What's happening?..

*P.S. I'd really love to ramble about politics and provide my ideas... but it's totally off-topic here so I'm asking from the technical point of view only ;)*

Answer (score 1):

IP geolocation doesn't actually depend on your location, but rather tabulated records. Different databases contain your IP or subnet assigned to different locations. For instance ipinfo.io gets my location correctly, while ipligence.com thinks I'm in Budaors, Hungary. Apparently Google has a similar mistake in their IP geolocation database.